# animate each path drawn in for loop

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am drawing paths using canvas. At a time 4 or more paths are drawn. animation works for single path but not works in 'for loop'. 
The paths are getting joined when I use Object Animator I want to draw separate paths with animation.

code to draw path

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            Log.v("x", "" + i + ": " + x[i]);
            Log.v("y", "" + i + ": " + y[i])
           mPath.quadTo(x0,y0, x[i],y[i]);

        PathMeasure measure = new PathMeasure(path, false);
        length = measure.getLength();
       ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(PathView.this, 
       "phase", 1.0f, 0.0f);
        animator.setDuration(3000);
        setPhase(length);
        animator.start();
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

            }
 public void setPhase(float phase)
    {
        Log.d("pathview","setPhase called with:" + String.valueOf(phase));
        paint.setPathEffect(createPathEffect(length, phase, 0.0f));

    }
public Paint getDashLine() {
        Paint fgPaintSel = new Paint();
        // fgPaintSel.setARGB(255, 255, 255,255);
        fgPaintSel.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        //fgPaintSel.setAlpha(120);

        fgPaintSel.setStrokeWidth(3);
        fgPaintSel.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);


        fgPaintSel.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{20, 20}, 0));


        return fgPaintSel;
    }
```

How can I draw each path with animation.

Comment: i want to animate each path. it works with single line. when i use it in for loop all the paths are getting joined. paths are separate lines

Comment: added getDashLine method, where i am creating paint object